# MouseListener is not working

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable within a ScrollPane that displays data retrieved from a database. What I want to achieve, is to make a row highlight at the right click. However, nothing happens, when I click the right button. Any help will be appreciated. Here are the code fragments:

[ItemTableModel.java]:

```
class ItemTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private final String[] modelColumnNames = {"Kod handlowy", "Nazwa", "Pojemność", "Napięcie", "Tolerancja", "Temp. min.", "Temp. maks.", "Ilość", "Cena", "Stan magazynowy"};
public Class[] modelColumnTypes = {String.class, String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class};
protected static ItemTableModel itemTableModel;
protected static JTable itemTable;

ArrayList<Item> modelData = new ArrayList<>();

public ItemTableModel(ArrayList<Item> dataArray) {
    super();
    modelData = dataArray;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return modelColumnNames.length;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return modelData.size();
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    Item data = modelData.get(row);

    switch (col) {
        case 0:
            data.setCommercialCode((String) value);
            break;
        case 1:
            data.setName((String) value);
            break;
        case 2:
            data.setCapacity((Integer) value);
            break;
        case 3:
            data.setVoltage((Integer) value);
            break;
        case 4:
            data.setTolerance((Integer) value);
            break;
        case 5:
            data.setTempMin((Integer) value);
            break;
        case 6:
            data.setTempMax((Integer) value);
            break;
        case 7:
            data.setQuantity((Integer) value);
            break;
        case 8:
            data.setPrice((Integer) value);
            break;
        case 9:
            data.setAvailability((Integer) value);
            break;

    }

}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return modelColumnNames[col];
}

@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
    return modelColumnTypes[col];
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Item data = modelData.get(row);

    switch (col) {
        case 0:
            return data.getCommercialCode();

        case 1:
            return data.getName();
        case 2:
            return data.getCapacity();
        case 3:
            return data.getVoltage();
        case 4:
            return data.getTolerance();
        case 5:
            return data.getTempMin();
        case 6:
            return data.getTempMax();
        case 7:
            return data.getQuantity();
        case 8:
            return data.getPrice();
        case 9:
            return data.getAvailability();

    }
    return new String();
}

protected static void CreateTable() {
    itemTableModel = new ItemTableModel(Retrieve.allItems);
    itemTable = new JTable(itemTableModel) {
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            Component component = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            int rendererWidth = component.getPreferredSize().width;
            TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
            tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(rendererWidth + getIntercellSpacing().width, tableColumn.getPreferredWidth()));
            return component;
        }
    };
    itemTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    itemTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void MousePressed(MouseEvent me){

            if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me)){
                int row = itemTable.rowAtPoint(me.getPoint());
                itemTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row,row);

            }
        }
    });

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(itemTable);
    Dimension d = itemTable.getPreferredSize();
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, itemTable.getRowHeight() * 10 + 1));
    MainWindow.TABLE.add(scrollPane);
    MainWindow.MAINFRAME.revalidate();
    MainWindow.getPasswordFrame().DisposePasswordFrame();
}
```

}

And here is, where the method is called:

[PasswordForm.java]

```
JButton loginButton = new JButton("Zaloguj");
    loginButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        if (usernameField != null && passwordField != null) {
            Retrieve.USER = usernameField.getText();
            Retrieve.PASS = passwordField.getText();

            Retrieve.Connect();

            ItemTableModel.CreateTable();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your question? What isn't working with your current approach? What error messages are you getting? Please read the [help/on-topic] about asking good questions.

Comment: Re `"Here are the code fragments:"` -- These are uncompilable and unrunnable fragments, and don't allow us to test or modify your code and see an effect. Much better would be for you to create and post a completely new program, a [minimal example program or mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that is very small, that compiles and runs for us, that has no code unrelated to your problem and that illustrates your problem for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void MousePressed(MouseEvent me){
```

The posted code looks reasonable, however you are overriding the wrong method. The method is `mousePressed`. Java is case sensitive.

This is why should always use the `@Override` annotation when overriding a method. Then the compiler can catch typos for you:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(...)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why I did not notice that!